# Two Contents Added With Space

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to add contents from two `DIV`s and inject them into an input field. The following works except there is no space in between the values entered.

With the code below the values in the text field is: `JohnDoeAccountant`
I'm looking for an output in the text field of: `John Doe Accountant`.

How could I ensure there is a space in between the values of the outputs?

```
var output1 = document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML;
var output2 = document.getElementById("lastname").innerHTML;
var output3 = document.getElementById("job").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = output1 + output2 + output3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = output1 + ' ' + output2 + ' ' + output3;
```

Comment: Thank You @xat - This works great I modified it a bit to add in commas in order to accept the tags as follows: document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = output1 + ', ' + output2 + ', ' + output3;

Answer (score 1):

```
....value = [output1, output2, output3].join(" ");
```

---

Or cut out some repetition:

```
document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = 
    ["firstname","lastname","job"].map(function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    }).join(" ")
```

---

Or like this:

```
document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = 
    ["firstname","lastname","job"].reduce(function(s, id) {
        return s + " " + document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    }, "")
```